# Alternatives to mysql for large reference tables

Tags: mysql, sharding

We currently use mysql for two types of tables:

The first set are the typical transaction based tables.

The second, are tables that are ones that store historical data which is usually write once, and read many times. They are large, hundreds of millions of rows or larger, and have a couple of indexes.

We have a couple of issues with these tables.

1. Any schema changes take forever
2. We’re not comfortable with the whole table being a single point of failure. If anything goes wrong, rebuilding this table would take ages.
3. It doesn't seem scalable

Are there any features of mysql we are missing that would alleviate these issues? I saw that MariaDB now has a way to add columns that doesn’t lock the whole table, but it doesn’t solve the other issues.

We’re also open to other products that might solve the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you ever need to add columns to Historical data?  Anyway, what values would you assign to the 'old' rows.

An alternative to adding a column is to create a "parallel" table (aka "verdical partitioning").  The new table would have the same `PRIMARY KEY` as the original (except for any `AUTO_INCREMENT` declaration).  You would use `LEFT JOIN` to fetch columns from both tables, and understand that 'old' rows would give you `NULLs` for the 'new' columns.

Another useful thing to do for Historical data is to treat it like a Fact table in Data Warehousing.  The build and maintain "Summary table(s)" to significantly speed up common "report" type queries.

In *newer* versions of MySQL/MariaDB, `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ... ALGORITHM=INPLACE` removes most of the performance pain.

Adding columns is also solved by moving toward EAV schema, which has a lot of bad qualities.  So, move only part-way toward such.  That is, keep the 5-10 main columns that you use for filtering and sorting as real columns, then put the rest of the key-value junk into a `JSON` column.  Both MySQL and MariaDB had such (though with some differences), plus MariaDB has "Dynamic Columns".

[Summary tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-summary-tables/)
[EAV](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/entity-attribute-value-implementation/)

"but it doesn’t solve the other issues" -- such as??

Comment: The reason for adding columns to historical tables is that we need to store new information going forward. The issue with adding new tables for just this new data, is that we would be double storing the key, which is relatively large (three varchar columns and a date column make the primary key)

Comment: Millions of `NULLs` takes space, too.  (Granted, not much space.)  It's a tradeoff.  Would you care to provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the existing History, plus definitions of new columns -- That should help us get a feel for the type of data and the 'relatively large' PK.  There may be other tips that would help.